# Azure WebApp Linux - Permission denied error when running node.js express app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a Linux Azure WebApp and I am trying to run a simple "Hello World!" with it using `NodeJs`, and `express`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
  app.get('/hello', async function(req,response) {
    return response.send('Hello World!');
  })
  app.listen( 80, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port 80!`),
);
```

To deploy the app, I have created a build pipeline in AzureDevOps. When the pipeline gets trigger to deploy the code into WebApp, I am getting **a permission denied error** when it try to **run app on port 80**.
[image]

I believe prot 80, is the right port to bind it, because If I provide `proccess.env.PORT` inside my code, instead of port 80, then I am getting **the port is already in use error.**

Below is the Azure DevOps configuration. I have entered `node server.js` as the command to be executed after the deployment is done.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Startup command from `npm install` to `npm run start` and clear your Inline Script selection.

Comment: that fixes the problem. Thank you!